# Mass Transit Integration Test: TestHarness Not Consuming Message

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I have setup a MassTransit integration test, but I am not able to get it to work. I am using the Web Application Factory to setup the integration test. I want to consume a message, then create a record in the database. I am able to verify that the test harness is publishing the message, but the harness never consumes the message. The function "IsMessageConsumedByService" always returns false. When I debug/step into function, the consumer harness always shows 0 messages consumed. Code is shown below. Any help appreciated.

**Web Application Factory**

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory
    : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly MsSqlContainer _mssqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder().Build();
    private readonly RabbitMqContainer _rabbitMqContainer = new RabbitMqBuilder().Build();
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll<TenantStoreDbContext>();
            services.RemoveAll<DbConnection>();
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<TenantStoreDbContext>));

            services.AddDbContext<TenantStoreDbContext>((container, options) =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_mssqlContainer.GetConnectionString());
            });

            services.AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<StripeSubscriptionCreatedConsumer>();
                // ToDo: Test with RabbitMq container after in memory works
            });
        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Local");
    }
    public async Task InitializeAsync() 
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync() 
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.DisposeAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.DisposeAsync();
    } 
}
```

**Test Class**

```
 public class NewTenantTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
    {
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory;

        public NewTenantTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void When_stripe_created_event_is_recieved_a_new_tenant_is_created()
        {
            // Arrange
            var serviceProvider = _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
            var testHarness = await StartTestHarness(serviceProvider);
            var subscriptionEvent = BuildStripeSubscriptionCreated();

            // Act
            await PublishMessage(subscriptionEvent, testHarness);

            // Assert
            (await IsMessageConsumedByService(testHarness, subscriptionEvent)).ShouldBe(true);
            (await IsMessageConsumedByConsumer(serviceProvider, subscriptionEvent)).ShouldBe(true);
            (await AssertNewTenantWasCreated(serviceProvider, subscriptionEvent.TenantIdentifier)).ShouldBe(true);

        }

        private static async Task<ITestHarness> StartTestHarness(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            var harness = provider.GetTestHarness();
            await harness.Start();

            return harness;
        }

        private static StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent BuildStripeSubscriptionCreated()
        {
            var subscriptionEvent = new StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent()
            {
                SubscriptionId = "abc",
                CustomerId = "abc",
                Description = "description",
                CurrentPeriodStart = DateTime.Now,
                CurrentPeriodEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                TenantIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

            return subscriptionEvent;
        }

        private static async Task PublishMessage(StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent subscriptionCreated, ITestHarness harness)
        {
            await harness.Bus.Publish(subscriptionCreated);
        }

        private static async Task<bool> IsMessageConsumedByConsumer(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent subscriptionCreated)
        {
            return await serviceProvider.
                GetRequiredService<IConsumerTestHarness<StripeSubscriptionCreatedConsumer>>().
                Consumed.Any<StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent>(x => x.Context.Message.EventId == subscriptionCreated.EventId);
        }

        private static async Task<bool> IsMessageConsumedByService(ITestHarness harness,
            StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent subscriptionCreated)
        {
            var consumerHarnes = harness.GetConsumerHarness<StripeSubscriptionCreatedConsumer>();
            return await consumerHarnes.Consumed.Any<StripeSubscriptionCreatedEvent>(x => x.Context.Message.EventId == subscriptionCreated.EventId);
        }

        private static async Task<bool> AssertNewTenantWasCreated(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string tenantIdentifier)
        {
            var repository = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITenantStoreRepository>();
            var identifier = TenantIdentifier.Create(tenantIdentifier).Value;
            var tenant = await repository.GetTenantByIdentifierAsync(identifier);

            return tenant != null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, without a standalone project reproducing the issue, it's impossible to guess.

I'd suggest adding logging to see what's happening, using the XUnit test output helper to your container before configuring the test harness. If your consumer is never getting the message, it could have been a myriad of reason under the covers as to why.

There are [articles](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-get-asp-net-core-logs-in-the-output-of-xunit-tests.htm) on how to get the test output from `ILogger` compatible sources.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. I got the harness consuming the messages, but the eventids don't match between the created message and the consumer context message in the harness. My messages all inherit from an abstract class that has a Guid property called EventId. Its value it set in the constructor. In the mass transit docs it says "If the message has a property named CorrelationId, CommandId, or EventId that is a Guid or Guid?, its value will be used." I thought the EventId value generated in the abstract class would be preserved? Am I not interpreting the docs correctly?

Comment: Got it all working. Abstract class had the EventId property defined as {get; private set}. Once I changed it to {get;init;}, it all worked.  I must of missed this in the docs.. Thankfully I reviewed them again "Properties with private set; are not recommended as they are not serialized by default when using System.Text.Json."