# MassTransit / xUnit: Tests are not always successful

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, masstransit

By using the xUnit framework, I want to write tests for my service. My project in general has the following structure:

1. I have a service where all consumers use the request-response model.
2. Each consumer, inside the Consume method, creates an appropriate DAL object, used for communicating with the database. For example, in a far fetched example of HelloWorld, the Hello consumer would create a HelloDataAccess object to fetch the string "Hello" from the database, while the World consumer would create a WorldDataAccess to fetch the string "World".
3. Each function inside these DAL objects require a connection object (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) and some other parameters, depending on the operation.
4. Every consumer's flow begins with the following check:

```
using (var connection = new DefaultDbConnection(this.configuration))
{
    if (connection.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        await connection.Connection.OpenAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

DefaultDbConnection is a custom object which has a static connection property, passed as a parameter in the DALs' functions.

Here is also the connection string that is used during the tests:

public const string DatabaseURL = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=myuser;" +
"Password=mypassword;" +
"Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=15;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;Pooling=true;" +
"Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=50;ConnectRetryInterval=5;ConnectRetryCount=20;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

For our tests, we use **docker**. Before running our tests, we create a database (and a redis) instance, populating it with all the required data, stored procedures etc.

In order to change the connection string in Test mode, we use a boolean in the DefaultDbConnection connection, when instantianting our test container:

```
DefaultDbConnection.IsTestMode = true;
```

```
if (IsTestMode)
{
    connectionString = configuration["LocalTestDbConnection"];
}
```

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"LocalTestDbConnection", TestConstants.DatabaseURL }
            })
            .Build();
```

My tests are all following the example from MassTransit's documentation:

```
[Test] 
public async Task An_example_unit_test() 
{
    await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddYourBusinessServices() // register all of your normal business services
        .AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
        })
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);

    var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

    await harness.Start();

    var client = harness.GetRequestClient<SubmitOrder>();

    var response = await client.GetResponse<OrderSubmitted>(new
    {
        OrderId = InVar.Id,
        OrderNumber = "123"
    });

    Assert.IsTrue(await harness.Sent.Any<OrderSubmitted>());

    Assert.IsTrue(await harness.Consumed.Any<SubmitOrder>());

    var consumerHarness = harness.GetConsumerHarness<SubmitOrderConsumer>();

    Assert.That(await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<SubmitOrder>());

    // test side effects of the SubmitOrderConsumer here
}
```

**The problem is** that all of our tests (counting 184) may run successfully for the first one, two or any number of times but may fail in the next try. The data, however, do not change and all the tests should run successfully every single time.

The errors that occur are:

1. Assert.True() Failure
   Expected: True
   Actual:   False

ExampleTest.ExampleTestCase() line 20

ExampleTest.ExampleTestCase() line 22

These lines refer to these calls:

line 20:

```
Assert.True(await harness.Consumed.Any<ConsumerRequestObject>());
```

line 21 & 22:

```
var consumerHarness = harness.GetConsumerHarness<ConsumerObject>();
Assert.True(await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<ConsumerRequestObject>());
```

2. Request time out.

In order to fix this problem, I have tried

1. Using RequestTimeout.None in my requests.
2. Changing the assembly of xUnit, by increasing the number of max parallel threads for example.
3. Changing the database url and increasing, for example, the maximum pool size.

Comment: Add logging to your unit test, [I've answered similarly in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289008/1882). And try setting parallelism to 1 ensuring all tests run isolated to rule out static/shared state in your underlying consumers, configuration code, etc.