# Message Not Consumed Testing SagaStateMachine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, masstransit

Trying to get a unit test with a SagaStateMachine to work by following the examples in github, [MassTransit Container Tests](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5232037c9ab8f7cf3fa587bc1985bebae7310669/tests/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/DependencyInjectionTestHarness_Specs.cs), but my test keeps failing

My SagaStateMachine setup is below

```
public class SubscriptionCreatedStateMachine :
    MassTransitStateMachine<SubscriptionCreatedState>
{
    public SubscriptionCreatedStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => StripeSubscriptionCreated, x =>
            x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.EventId));

        Event(() => FinbuckleTenantCreated, x => 
            x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.CorrelationId));

        Initially(
            When(StripeSubscriptionCreated)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Saga.TenantId = context.Message.TenantId;
                    context.Saga.Identifier = context.Message.TenantId; // The identifier for a new tenant is always the tenant id (GUID)
                    context.Saga.SubscriptionId = context.Message.SubscriptionId;
                    context.Saga.CustomerId = context.Message.CustomerId;
                    context.Saga.CustomerEmail = context.Message.CustomerEmail;
                    context.Saga.Description = context.Message.Description;
                    context.Saga.CurrentPeriodStart = context.Message.CurrentPeriodStart;
                    context.Saga.CurrentPeriodEnd = context.Message.CurrentPeriodEnd;
                    context.Saga.Created  = context.Message.Created;
                })
                .TransitionTo(SubscriptionCreated)
                .Publish(context => new CreateTenant()
                {
                    CorrelationId = context.Saga.CorrelationId,
                    TenantId = context.Saga.TenantId,
                    Identifier = context.Saga.Identifier, 
                    SubscriptionId = context.Saga.SubscriptionId,
                    CustomerId = context.Saga.CustomerId,
                    CustomerEmail = context.Saga.CustomerEmail,
                    Description = context.Saga.Description,
                    CurrentPeriodStart = context.Saga.CurrentPeriodStart,
                    CurrentPeriodEnd = context.Saga.CurrentPeriodEnd,
                    Created = context.Saga.Created
                })
        );

        During(SubscriptionCreated,
                    When(FinbuckleTenantCreated)
                        .TransitionTo(TenantCreated)
                        .Publish(context => new SendTenantCreatedEmail()
                        {
                            CorrelationId = context.Saga.CorrelationId,
                            Identifier = context.Saga.Identifier,
                            CustomerEmail = context.Saga.CustomerEmail,
                            CurrentPeriodStart = context.Saga.CurrentPeriodStart,
                            CurrentPeriodEnd = context.Saga.CurrentPeriodEnd
                        })
        );
    }

    public State SubscriptionCreated { get; } = null!;
    public State TenantCreated { get; } = null!;
    public Event<StripeSubscriptionCreated> StripeSubscriptionCreated { get; } = null!;
    public Event<TenantCreated> FinbuckleTenantCreated { get;  }= null!;
}
```

Here is my unit test. My test harness consumes the StripeSubscriptionCreated event, but my saga harness assertions never pass. I must be missing something, but don't see it.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Can_consume_stripe_subscription_created_event()
{
    await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<SubscriptionCreatedStateMachine, SubscriptionCreatedState>()
                .InMemoryRepository();
        })
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);

    var harness = provider.GetTestHarness();
    await harness.Start();

    var subscriptionEvent = new StripeSubscriptionCreated()
    {
        SubscriptionId = "abc",
        CustomerId = "abc",
        CustomerEmail = "customer@email.com",
        Description = "description",
        CurrentPeriodStart = DateTime.UtcNow,
        CurrentPeriodEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1),
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
        TenantId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };

    await harness.Bus.Publish(subscriptionEvent);

    (await harness.Consumed.Any<StripeSubscriptionCreated>()).ShouldBeTrue();

    var sagaHarness = harness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<SubscriptionCreatedStateMachine, SubscriptionCreatedState>();  
    (await sagaHarness.Consumed.Any<StripeSubscriptionCreated>()).ShouldBeTrue();
    (await sagaHarness.Created.Any(x => x.CorrelationId == subscriptionEvent.EventId)).ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated

Comment: Logs, logs, review the logs... https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289008/1882